# Select option data flickering in laravel livewire page

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

In my page, I am using polling to refresh current status of an event.
In the same page, I have one dropdown(select). When I click the dropdown, the data inside it like flickering. SO, I think it is related to polling request.

I tried using wire:ignore.self and wire:model.defer but the issue still there.

Answer (score -1):

Since the wire polling is updating DOM, try adding `wire:ignore` (and not `wire:ignore.self`) on `<select>` tag.

Comment: Yes I have done both. wire:ignore and wire:ignore.self. But still cannot solve it.

Comment: Any update for this issue ?